# Multivariable-calculus. Find the stationary point (critical point)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I got the function $f(x,y)=\ln(1+x^2+y^2)$. The task is to find the stationary points. The correct answer is $(0,0)$. How do I find the stationary point? I`ve differentiated it at put it equal to zero like this:

$$f_x(x,y)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}=0$$

$$f_y(x,y)=\frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2}=0$$

But then how do I find the stationary point?

Comment: What happens when you multiply both sides (of each equation) by their, nonzero, denominators?

Answer (score 1):

$f'_x(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $2x = 0 \iff x=0$.

Likewise, $f'_y(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $2y = 0 \iff y = 0$.

Hence, the only stationary point is $(x, y) = (0,0)$, since only at the point $(0,0)$ both $f'_x(x, y) = f'_y(x, y) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The critical/stationary points satisfy the equations $f_x(x,y)=0$ and $f_y(x,y)=0$ simultaneously.